# Karate properties.json throws ReferenceError when Reading Properties in *.feature file

Tags: json, properties, karate

Having updated Karate from 0.6.2 to 0.9.5 recently I've had a number of ReferenceError's w.r.t the properties.json I've used throughout my test cases.

I've the following setup:

#### test-properties.json

```
{
    "headers": {
        "x-client-ip": "192.168.3.1",
        "x-forwarded-for": "192.168.3.1"
    }
}
```

#### test-auth.feature

```
  Background:
      * def props = read('properties/test-properties.json')
```

I then use `props` further down in my first scenario:

```
And header User-Agent = props.headers.Accept-Language
And header X-Forwarded-For = props.headers.x-forwarded-for
```

However, when running this I get the following issue:

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: test-auth.feature:14 - javascript evaluation failed: props.headers.Accept-Language, ReferenceError: "Language" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
```

I've tried adding the properties file into the same package as the `test-auth.feature` to no avail. The issue seems to be with reading the json file. I'm aware Karate 0.6.2 could evaluate the file type and parse it internally in its native format. Is this still the case? If not, what is the solution to reading from properties.json in Karate 0.9.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing should have changed when it comes to reading JSON files. Karate evaluates the RHS as JS, so I think this is the solution:

```
And header User-Agent = props.headers['Accept-Language']
And header X-Forwarded-For = props.headers['x-forwarded-for']
```

EDIT: this works for me:

```
* def props = { headers: { 'Accept-Language': 'foo', 'x-forwarded-for': 'bar' } }
* url 'http://httpbin.org/headers'
* header User-Agent = props.headers['Accept-Language']
* header X-Forwarded-For = props.headers['x-forwarded-for']
* method get
```

Resulting in:

```
1 > GET http://httpbin.org/headers
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Host: httpbin.org
1 > User-Agent: foo
1 > X-Forwarded-For: bar
```

So if you are still stuck, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I'm still getting a javascript evaluation failed error when trying this solution:  

    `javascript evaluation failed: props.headers.['x-forwarded-for'], <eval>:1:14 Expected ident but found [
props.headers.['x-forwarded-for']
              ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 14`

Comment: Cheers, injecting the JSON in the feature works. I may raise a ticket in the future if my JSON becomes slightly larger, as it's cleaner to have the *.properties.json in it's own file and have it injected that way. Many thanks.

Comment: @Magu there should be no difference if you inject or read from a file. which is why I would urge you to consider submitting a working example, because if there is a bug, I'd like to fix it